# Can a non-convex polyhedral angle have the sum of plane angles smaller than $180^\circ$?

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, 3d, angle

> **Can a non-convex polyhedral angle have the sum of plane angles smaller than $180^\circ$?**

---

I don't have a fully-fledged attempt. I've only been able to gather some potentially useful facts.

Here's what I got:

**Given:** non-convex polyhedral angle SABCD, where sides ASD and DSC are concave.

- $|ASD-DSC| < ASC < ASD+DSC$
- $ASD+DSC+CSB+BSA<360$
- |difference of two plane angles adjacent angles| < angle < sum of two adjacent angles

---

I'm sure the answer is "no", out of intuition. **How can I prove it, though?**

Comment: What do you mean by non convex polyhedral angle?

Comment: @Del -- According the the textbook from which this question is posed (Kiselev's Geometry, Book 2: Stereometry), "non-convex" means concave.